# yii chtml link not working properly

Tags: php, yii

I have a absolute url: http://www.linkbook.co/

When I use a `grid view` and within a `column` I use:

```
        array(
            'type' => 'raw',
            'header' => 'Url',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->location,$data->location,array("target"=>"_blank"))',
        ),
```

, when a user clicks on the link, a new tab opens within the browser;

Now, if the link is not absolute, `yii chtml link` concats the app current url with given url, so I get:

`http://localhost/frontend/user/url/index/id/www.william.ro`

What can I do in order to get a new tab opened with the not absolute url?

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way were this:

```
array(
    'header'=>'Url',
    'name'=>'location',
    'type'=>'url',
),
```

This will invoke [CFormatter.formatUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter#formatUrl-detail), which will automatically prepend `http://` if no scheme is found.

Answer (score 1):

follow this [link](http://yiiapi.com/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail) :

Normalizes the input parameter to be a valid URL.

If the input parameter is an empty string, the currently requested URL will be returned.

If the input parameter is a non-empty string, it is treated as a valid URL and will be returned without any change.

If the input parameter is an array, it is treated as a controller route and a list of GET parameters, and the CController::createUrl method will be invoked to create a URL. In this case, the first array element refers to the controller route, and the rest key-value pairs refer to the additional GET parameters for the URL. For example, array('post/list', 'page'=>3) may be used to generate the URL /index.php?r=post/list&page=3.